# Refresh div on checkbox state change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get my div with id "ship-info-update" to refresh when my checkbox is checked or unchecked. I searched around quite a bit, but I can't seem to get anything to work properly.

Here is part of my _form.html.erb

```
  <%= field_set_tag "Shipping Info" do %>
    <%= f.input :noship, :as => :boolean, label: 'No physical goods will be shipped', :id => "noship-checkbox" %>

    <div id="ship-info-update">

      <%= f.simple_fields_for :package do |p| %>

        <% if @campaign.noship == true %>
          <%= @campaign.weight = 0 %>
        <% else %>
          <%= p.input :weight, hint: 'Package weight of one unit in pounds (lbs)' %>
        <% end %>

      <% end %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

Comment: The underscore in `_form.html.erb` tells me this is a partial, which can't actually be independently "refreshed" from the server. Can you add more detail about wha you want the JS to do?

Comment: When the "noship f.input field" checkbox is checked or unchecked I want to refresh the "ship-info-update div" so that the "if" below it will either create or not create the "weight p.input field" based on the checkbox value. Maybe what I am thinking of is not possible?

Comment: Why would you need a server round trip for that? `$("#weight").val(0).hide()`